# how to run command prompt in .Bat file

Tags: batch-file

I read many website for finding my answer but I couldn't understand many of them.
So I need your help, I want make one bat file for run Command prompt commands and save my time.
This is my command :

```
dispatch -V  
dispatch list  
dispatch start 192.168.1.15@1 192.168.1.20@1 --http
```

And It Doesn't have to exit after these code.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
dispatch -V  
dispatch list  
dispatch start 192.168.1.15@1 192.168.1.20@1 --http  
pause >nul
```

**Explanation:** 
1) `@echo off` removes

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] 
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\microsoft>
```

and all the current path you're accessing.
2) `pasue >nul` don't show `Press any key to continue...`, if you want it to display on console, change it to `pause`.

Comment: It doesn't work and closes immediately after opening. Why ? I tried to save file to .bat, Also I tried to save with Notepad++ but Doesn't work.

Comment: That means your provided code is not working, even it's working, some command wasn't the same in console and .bat file.

Comment: This code working well when I'm using command prompt, I'm using this code for Combine internet connections.

Comment: The commands you have shown simply need to be listed as dark fang has shown.  What name did you give the batch script?

Comment: @foxidrive  I used many name but Doesn't make any different, For example I'm using : new 1.bat

Comment: You can try replacing `dispatch` to `dispatch.js`, not sure it will work.

Comment: Seems doesn't work, 'dispatch.js' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: First I installed the Node.js then I use that codes I mentioned then It's work and running.

Comment: So do you mean you install dispatch with Node.js and run directly from CMD?

Comment: Yes, before run these commands node.js must install then install dispatch, now Cmd with those commands must work. Node.js > Dispatch > Cmd

Comment: Try adding `pause` under each line of your code, and then tell me if there's any error messages appear on Cmd.

Comment: @darkfang   I found way ! I deleted dispatch -V then It's work ... I don't know why ! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @SoheilJamehBozorg  The reason I asked about the name is because you may have used `dispatch.bat` which will then just call itself.